# Updating regex for extracting IBAN's

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex which extracts German and Austrian IBANs. However, I just realized, that html code sometimes has strange format.

```
\b(?:DE|AT)(?:\s?[0-9a-zA-Z]){18}(?:(?:\s?[0-9a-zA-Z]){2})?\b
```

Therefore I have to exclude not valid IBAN matches. In my [demo](https://regex101.com/r/PRDDaT/8) I show examples which show missmatches. How would you exclude this?

Comment: Remove the chars a-z and use a space instead of `\s` like  `\b(?:DE|AT)(?: ?[0-9]){18}(?:(?: ?[0-9]){2})?\b` https://regex101.com/r/aWQcKX/1

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This makes sense. Problem solved :-)

Comment: Maybe rethink the pattern you have used to extract valid IBAN. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65735302/9758194) is a start under your own previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you only want to match digits. Therefore you can remove `a-zA-Z` from the character classes. Also note that `\s` could also match a newline, so if you don't want the match to span over newlines, you can match an optional space instead.

```
\b(?:DE|AT)(?: ?[0-9]){18}(?:(?: ?[0-9]){2})?\b
```

See the updated [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aWQcKX/1)